# Backbone.js with compound keys

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, composite-key, composite-primary-key

**Is it possible to make Backbone.js work with compound keys?**

Id est, instead of setting `id` or `idAttributemodel` to a specific value, I want to know Backbone.js that I will be using more than one property. In such a way, every RESTful call would be made sending those two parameters to identify the object we're talking about.

For the sake of an example, let's say that I want to update a person's debt to a specific person, and the model is:

```
Borrower (borrowerId, name, ...)
Lender (lenderId, name, ...)
Debt (borrowerId, lenderId, debtAmount)
```

So, I now want to make Backbone.js update/delete a debt object. How can I make it work with the compound key `(borrowerId, lenderId)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override the `url()` implementation of your model, as suggested in [Backbone's documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-url):

```
var Debt = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    var base = /* your base URL here */;
    if (this.isNew()) return base;
    return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + encodeURIComponent(this.get("borrowerId")+"_"+this.get("lenderId"));
  }
});
```

The above code would result in URLs of the form `baseURL/borrowerId_lenderId`. Note that you may want to take a collections base URL into account when constructing the model's URL.

Comment: Thanks! How would you set up the `id` or `idAttribute` values to follow this convention as well?

Comment: It seems overriding url() isn't enough. I had to also override parse() to generate the fake id from the compound keys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199615/backbone-does-post-instead-of-put-on-updates-when-composite-key-is-used Then it works perfectly.

Comment: The follow-up question re: `id` or `idAttribute` is that you can configure your model to use a composite key using  `idAttribute: ["borrowerId", "lenderId"]`.

Comment: I don't think `idAttribute: ["borrowerId", "lenderId"]` will work.  This will cause Backbonen to always issue `create`(POST) instead of `update`(PUT) messages cause this `this.isNew()` will always return true.

Comment: Another props will work: `idAttributes`. It's composite so another S just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the URL function and the modelid function on a collection.  The URL by default only knows what to do with a single attribute so you need a way to map it.

A collection uses a dictionary to find elements during a get. There is a modelId function that will covert a model into a strong that represents the key to use in the dictionary.  For compounds you make it return '' + id1 + '-' + id2 or similar.