# Backbone does POST instead of PUT on updates when composite key is used

Tags: backbone.js, model, composite-key

I'm using a composite key in my model and generate the ID based on my composite key:

```
app.Assignment = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute : [ 'personId', 'jobId' ],
    parse : function(resp) {
        resp.id = resp.personId + "_" + resp.jobId;
        return resp;
    }
});
```

but Backbone still thinks that all instances of Assignment are new, allthough I'm setting the id in the parse method when fetching them from the API. As a result Backbone does no DELETEs and does a POST instead of PUT on updates. How can I work around this or what is the "right way" to do it?

**Update:**

Looks like replacing resp.id with this.id solves the issue.

Comment: Backbone doesn't support composite keys, so defining `idAttribute` as an array is not valid. Every model must have one id field. What do your resource URLs look like?

Comment: It does support composite keys: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/1558 actually I solved it by doing this.id = ... instead of resp.ide = ...

Comment: Ah, you're using https://github.com/caseywebdev/backbone-composite-keys. Would've made sense to mention it in the question.

Comment: doesn't doing that parse thing eliminate the reason to use the composite keys?

Answer (score 2):

The results of the `parse` method of a Backbone.Model are passed to the `set` method, which sets the *attributes* of the model.  The point of confusion for you I think is that the model's ID isn't one of it's attributes; it's one of its *properties*.

So, what happens is this:

1. Your raw data comes back from the server and is passed to `parse`
2. That same raw data, now augmented with a `id` attribute, is passed to `set`
3. `set` looks and your `idAttribute` (`[ 'personId', 'jobId' ]`) and all of the keys in the raw data
4. Since none of those keys match the `idAttribute`, none of them are used as the model's ID, and thus you get your problem.

Your solution of setting `this.id` inside `parse` works, but it might cause problems down the road because parse is generally designed to operate on it's input (the raw data), not to modify the model itself; that part is supposed to happen next when `set` is called.  A cleaner solution would instead be to do something like the following:

```
app.Assignment = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // note that no idAttribute is specified, leaving it as the default "id"
    parse : function(resp) {
        resp.id = resp.personId + "_" + resp.jobId;
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Or, if you want a different ID attribute ...

```
app.Assignment = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'personAndJobId',
    parse : function(resp) {
        resp.personAndJobId = resp.personId + "_" + resp.jobId;
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the `idAttribute` issues here, you can always force Backbone to use a certain HTTP method via the type options passed to `save()`.

`model.save(null, { type: 'put' })`

Answer (score 0):

I've never work with composite ID in Backbone, but I think this could be an easy answer to your problem:

```
initialize: function() {
      this.set("id", this.generateID());
},
generateID = function () {
    return this.personId + + "_" + this.jobId;
}
```

With this code in you Backbone model definition you are creating a unique ID for each model and you shouldn't have problems for update and save it (and you don't need to set any idAttribute).